# show an image sent from android client using socket

Tags: android, html, node.js

I'm trying to show an image on a html page, I received the image from the android client (base64), now I want to make it appears on a html page.

This is the code of the reception, I don't know what is the next step.

```
socket.on("image", function (image) {        //réception d'une image 
                    console.log(" image réçu : " +image)
                    //use fs.writeFile
                    image = image.replace(/^data:image\/png;base64,/, "");
                    require("fs").writeFile("out.png", image, 'base64',function(err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    });

                });
```

Comment: Is this on the server side or the web client side? If its web client side, then you can just set the `src` attribute of the image `div` with the base64 string that you received using jQuery or JavaScript. If its server side, where exactly are you planning to show it?

Comment: this is the server side , and i'm planning to show it on the web client side.

Comment: Check my answer, it should help.

Comment: It does not matter how you uploaded `out.png` to your server. If you want to show it with `<img src ="out.png" ` then your html page or the generating script should be in the same page as your image.

Answer (score 0):

As you said this is server side, What you can do is, emit the base64 code as it is to the web client. And on the web client, use JavaScript to replace the `src` attribute of the image div where you are planning to display the image.

Client side sample code below:

```
Socket.on("image", function(){
    document.getElementById('img').setAttribute( 'src', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==' );
}
```

This shold work, in the place of the dummy base64 that I used, you can use yours.

Comment: see my answer , and tell me what to change

Comment: @MoezBenAhmed You have not written any Socket code for you web client?